# How to redirect typeform webpage after submit button is clicked, embedded on personal website?

Tags: html, redirect, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

**[Very new to setting up websites]**

I am running `ubuntu` and `apache2` and have successfully embedded `typeform` survey in an html page hosted on a webserver.

In the typeform survey I have a '`submit`' button that is supposed to redirect back to the 'home screen' of the typeform survey.

However on my server when I click this button, I get an error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at subdomain.website.com Port 80
```

I also notice the word 'self' appears in the URL, like so:

```
http://subdomain.website.com/self
```

I have added/modifed the following lines too the apache2.conf document:

```
1. Added - LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
2. Modifed - all strings 'AllowOverride None' to 'AllowOverride All'
```

and restarted the server. But I dont see any change. How can I redirect the submit button to the 'home scree' of the typeform survey that is embedded?

I used this [document](https://help.typeform.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029249212-Embed-your-typeform) to generate the embed code for the html document that I put on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a built-in feature on Typeform, you can decide where the user will be redirected when completing the form.

There is a detailed explanation of how to activate it on [Typeform Help Center](https://help.typeform.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029257112-Redirect-on-completion).

You basically have to go to your form settings and activate the `redirect on completion` option.

There you could put the URL of your choice, and even use the user's answers as parameters to pass to the URL.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Do you stay embedded after the redirect? Or does it redirect the whole page? In my testing, it redirects the whole page is not ideal. It would be better if we can specify to redirect within the embed.

Comment: For security reason, it's not recommended to redirect in the iframe so it rather redirects the host page.
If you want to redirect into the embed div you can use the Typeform Embed SDK https://developer.typeform.com/embed/ and listen to the `onSubmit` callback when the form submits. You would be able to delete the embed and display the iframe of your choice.

Comment: Awesome, definitely going to try that. It would be slick though if Typeform natively supported this in some way at a higher level because its a really powerful way to construct wizards or multi-branched forms. I know TF can have logic jumps within a single form, but this is cumbersome to manage and doesn't make sense when constructing menus that direct to very different forms which should have their own submissions and analytics.